# on() doesn't work in binding function in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is working

```
$("#closePreviewPhoto" + filesId).on('click',function(){
        $('#list' + filesId).html("");
        $('#files' + filesId).val("");
        $('.thumb-canvas' + filesId).css('display','none');
      });
```

but it doesn't work when I tried to separate it and use function :

```
function removePhoto(filesId){
    $('#list' + filesId).html("");
    $('#files' + filesId).val("");
    $('.thumb-canvas' + filesId).css('display','none');
}

$("#closePreviewPhoto" + filesId).on('click', removePhoto(filesId));
```

where is my mistake?

Answer (score 5):

You're passing the result of the function call instead of the function.

Change

```
$("#closePreviewPhoto" + filesId).on('click', removePhoto(filesId));
```

to

```
$("#closePreviewPhoto" + filesId).on('click', function(){
    removePhoto(filesId)
});
```

Now, note that there's probably a much simpler solution than to iterate over all your `filesId` to bind a function, you can do the binding directly on all matching elements and deduce `filesId` from the clicked element id :

```
$("[id^=closePreviewPhoto]").on('click', function(){
    var filesId = this.id.slice("closePreviewPhoto".length);
    $('#list' + filesId).html("");
    $('#files' + filesId).val("");
    $('.thumb-canvas' + filesId).css('display','none');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the function as passing the value returned by it(in this case undefined) as the event handler, instead of passing it as a event handler

```
$("#closePreviewPhoto" + filesId).on('click', function(){
    removePhoto(filesId)
});
```

Also the parameter `filesId` looks like a closure variable, if you can share more context to the problem we can have a better look